# Is it possible to use Cypress e2e testing with a firebase auth project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, cypress

I am exploring Cypress for e2e testing, looks like great software.
The problem is Authentication, the Cypress documentation explains why using the UI is very bad [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/testing-your-app.html#Logging-In).

So I tried looking at the network tap of my application, to see if I could create a POST request to the firebase API, and authenticate without using the GUI. But I can see that there at least 2 request fired, and token saved to application storage.

So what approach should I use?

1. Authenticate with the UI of my application, and instruct Cypress not to touch the local storage
2. Keep experimenting with a way of sending the correct POST requests, and save the values to local storage.
3. Make Cypress run custom JS code, and then use the Firebase SDK to login.

I am really looking for some advice here :)

Comment: Just commenting to note that it looks like Firebase has altered their implementation to store auth data in indexedDB instead of localStorage, so accepted solutions will no longer work.

Comment: Hi @Dygerati thanks for pointing this out, I will investigate

Comment: @Dygerati have you found a solution to this? I still have no way of accessing my data in my cypress tests

Comment: @NateMay I had to do the same thing with access data, the answer I posted includes custom commands for doing that.

Answer (score 10):

When doing this myself I made custom commands (like `cy.login` for auth then `cy.callRtdb` and `cy.callFirestore` for verifying data). After getting tired of repeating the logic it took to build them, I wrapped it up into a library called [cypress-firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-firebase). It includes custom commands and a cli to generate a custom auth token.

Setup mostly just consists of adding the custom commands in `cypress/support/commands.js`:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import { attachCustomCommands } from 'cypress-firebase';

const fbConfig = {
    // Your config from Firebase Console
};

window.fbInstance = firebase.initializeApp(fbConfig);

attachCustomCommands({ Cypress, cy, firebase })
```

And adding the plugin to `cypress/plugins/index.js`:

```
const cypressFirebasePlugin = require('cypress-firebase').plugin

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `config` is the resolved Cypress config

  // Return extended config (with settings from .firebaserc)
  return cypressFirebasePlugin(config)
}
```

But there full details on setup [are available in the setup docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-firebase#setup).

Disclosure, I am the author of [cypress-firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-firebase), which is the whole answer.

Comment: That's awesome - so after setting this up you can simply call `cy.login`?

Comment: @DauleDK That is correct! I am also actively working on more features since my team uses it. Here is an article explaining how to set it up: https://medium.com/@prescottprue/testing-react-firebase-apps-with-cypress-7d7a64d155de.

Disclosure: I am the author of the tool being discussed in the answer and the article posted in this comment.

Comment: Yes it does, we run all of our tests on CI using it. We have found Gitlab to be the easiest to setup for running Cypress tests.

Answer (score 3):

I took the approach of using automated UI to obtain the contents of localStorage used by Firebase JS SDK. I also wanted to do this only once per whole Cypress run so I did it before the Cypress start.

1. Obtain Firebase SDK localStorage entry via *pupeteer*
2. Store the contents in the tmp file (problems passing it via env var to Cypress)
3. Pass the file location to Cypress via env var and let it read the contents and set the localStorage to setup the session

Helper script which obtains contents of localStorage:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const invokeLogin = async page => {
    await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/login')

    await page.waitForSelector('.btn-googleplus')
    await page.evaluate(() =>
        document.querySelector('.btn-googleplus').click())
}

const doLogin = async (page, {username, password}) => {

    // Username step
    await page.waitForSelector('#identifierId')
    await page.evaluate((username) => {
        document.querySelector('#identifierId').value = username
        document.querySelector('#identifierNext').click()
    }, username)

    //  Password step
    await page.waitForSelector('#passwordNext')
    await page.evaluate(password =>
            setTimeout(() => {
                document.querySelector('input[type=password]').value = password
                document.querySelector('#passwordNext').click()
            }, 3000) // Wait 3 second to next phase to init (couldn't find better way)
        , password)
}

const extractStorageEntry = async page =>
    page.evaluate(() => {
        for (let key in localStorage) {
            if (key.startsWith('firebase'))
                return {key, value: localStorage[key]}
        }
    })

const waitForApp = async page => {
    await page.waitForSelector('#app')
}

const main = async (credentials, cfg) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(cfg)
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await invokeLogin(page)
    await doLogin(page, credentials)
    await waitForApp(page)
    const entry = await extractStorageEntry(page)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(entry))
    await browser.close()
}

const username = process.argv[2]
const password = process.argv[3]

main({username, password}, {
    headless: true // Set to false for debugging
})
```

Since there were problem with sending JSON as environment variables to Cypress I use tmp file to pass the data between the script and the Cypress  process.

```
node test/getFbAuthEntry ${USER} ${PASSWORD} > test/tmp/fbAuth.json
cypress open --env FB_AUTH_FILE=test/tmp/fbAuth.json
```

In Cypress I read it from the file system and set it to the localStorage

```
const setFbAuth = () =>
    cy.readFile(Cypress.env('FB_AUTH_FILE'))
        .then(fbAuth => {
            const {key, value} = fbAuth
            localStorage[key] = value
        })

describe('an app something', () => {
    it('does stuff', () => {
        setFbAuth()
        cy.viewport(1300, 800)
...
```

Comment: This solution is very interesting, because I can see that you use google as auth provider. I only work with email and password, so it was actually relatively easy to just use the API's. How is performance?

Comment: Yep. In the project where it is used there are 3 auth providers - Facebook, Google and email. I didn't want to get dependent on internals of Firebase as it would make tests more brittle. The setup takes cca 5 seconds but it is fine as it is done only once for all the tests.

Comment: Unfortunately Firebase just switched over to indexedDB, so this localstorage solution no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly a hack but to get around the login part for the app I am working on I use the `beforeEach` hook to login to the application.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.resetTestDatabase().then(() => {
    cy.setupTestDatabase();
  });
});
```

Which is derived from my helper functions.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
  return firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(Cypress.env('USER_EMAIL'), Cypress.env('USER_PASSWORD'));
});

Cypress.Commands.add('resetTestDatabase', () => {
  return cy.login().then(() => {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(DEFAULT_CATEGORIES_PATH)
      .once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
        const defaultCategories = snapshot.val();
        const updates = {};
        updates[TEST_CATEGORIES_PATH] = defaultCategories;
        updates[TEST_EVENTS_PATH] = null;
        updates[TEST_STATE_PATH] = null;
        updates[TEST_EXPORT_PATH] = null;

        return firebase
          .database()
          .ref()
          .update(updates);
      });
  });
});
```

What I would like to know is how the information coming back from `firebase` ultimately gets saved to `localStorage`. I don't really have an answer to this but it works. Also, the app uses `.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())` whereas above it signs in with email and password. So I am kind of shortcutting the signin process only because `cypress` has the CORS limitation.

Answer (score 2):

At the time writing, I've examined these approaches

- stubbing firebase network requests - really difficult. A bunch of firebase requests is sent continuously. There are so many request params & large payload and they're unreadable.
- localStorage injection - as same as request stubbing. It requires an internally thorough understanding of both firebase SDK and data structure.
- cypress-firebase plugin - it's not matured enough and lack of documentation. I skipped this option because it needs a service account (admin key). The project I'm working on is opensource and there are many contributors. It's hard to share the key without including it in the source control.

Eventually, I implemented it on my own which is quite simple. Most importantly, it doesn't require any confidential firebase credentials. Basically, it's done by

- initialize another firebase instance within Cypress
- use that firebase instance to build a Cypress custom command to login

---

```js
    const fbConfig = {
      apiKey: `your api key`, // AIzaSyDAxS_7M780mI3_tlwnAvpbaqRsQPlmp64
      authDomain: `your auth domain`, // onearmy-test-ci.firebaseapp.com
      projectId: `your project id`, // onearmy-test-ci

    }
    firebase.initializeApp(fbConfig)
    
    const attachCustomCommands = (
      Cypress,
      { auth, firestore }: typeof firebase,
    ) => {
      let currentUser: null | firebase.User = null
      auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        currentUser = user
      })
    
      Cypress.Commands.add('login', (email, password) => {
        Cypress.log({
          displayName: 'login',
          consoleProps: () => {
            return { email, password }
          },
        })
        return auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      })
    
      Cypress.Commands.add('logout', () => {
        const userInfo = currentUser ? currentUser.email : 'Not login yet - Skipped'
        Cypress.log({
          displayName: 'logout',
          consoleProps: () => {
            return { currentUser: userInfo }
          },
        })
        return auth().signOut()
      })

    }
    
    attachCustomCommands(Cypress, firebase)
```

Here is the commit that has all integration code https://github.com/ONEARMY/community-platform/commit/b441699c856c6aeedb8b73464c05fce542e9ead1

Comment: This looks to be out of date. It didn't work for me, and it looks like that codebase has since updated the solution too.

it doesn't seem to work with two firebase auth instances on the same window, so I, and that codebase too, have shared the firebase instance from the app to Cypress via window (https://github.com/ONEARMY/community-platform/commit/6872a5f70433af02c23a88d2ace67f9cd4bbe830)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>This is becoming way easier with the upcoming [Auth emulator](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1677).</strike> This has become easier with the [Firebase Auth Emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth) (`firebase-tools` >= 8.1.4).

`cypress/support/signAs.js`:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('signAs', (uid, opt) => {
  cy.visit('/')

  cy.window().its('firebase').then( fb => {
    cy.wrap( (async _ => {
      // Create a user based on the provided token (only '.uid' is used by Firebase)
      await fb.auth().signInWithCustomToken( JSON.stringify({ uid }) );

      // Set '.displayName', '.photoURL'; for email and password, other functions exist (not implemented)
      await fb.auth().currentUser.updateProfile(opt);
    })() )
  })
})
```

Use it as:

```
cy.signAs('joe', { displayName: 'Joe D.', photoURL: 'http://some' });
```

If you need to set `.email` or `.password`, there are similar functions for those, but this was sufficient for my tests. I can now impersonate any user ad-hoc, as part of the test. The approach does not need users to be created in the emulator; you can just claim to be one, with the particular uid. Works well for me.

Note:

Firebase authentication is in IndexedDB (as mentioned in other answers) and Cypress does not clear it, between the tests. There is discussion about this in [cypress #1208](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1208).

Comment: Update: the auth emulator is now available in v.8.14

Comment: hey, I'm doing basically the same, but with emulator it complains on Same Origin policy and fails to call localhost:9099 - do you know what's the issue in this case?

Comment: @Ianwen No idea. Are you using a `demo-...` project name to make sure Firebase won't try to reach for the cloud?  Also, the client has changed considerably in 9.x.

[Here](https://github.com/akauppi/GroundLevel-firebase-es/blob/master/packages/app/cypress/_commands/index.js#L54-L80) is how the above code snippet has evolved. I remember it being tricky to get this right, but no recollection of Same Origin issues.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after much trial and error, I tried solution path 2 and it worked.

So my auth flow looks like this:

1. Send POST request (using cybress.request) to
   `https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword`,
   and parse the response. Create an object: `response1 = response.body`
2. Send POST request (using cybress.request) to
   `https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getAccountInfo`,
   use the idToken from the prev request. Create an object: `user = response2.body.users[0];`

Combine the response in an object, with the following properties:

```
const authObject = {
  uid: response1.localId,
  displayName: response1.displayName,
  photoURL: null,
     email: response1.email,
     phoneNumber: null,
     isAnonymous: false,
     providerData: [
       {
          uid: response1.email,
          displayName: response1.displayName,
          photoURL: null,
          email: body.email,
          phoneNumber: null,
          providerId: 'password'
       }
      ],
      'apiKey': apiKey,
      'appName': '[DEFAULT]',
      'authDomain': '<name of firebase domain>',
      'stsTokenManager': {
         'apiKey': apiKey,
         'refreshToken': response1.refreshToken,
         'accessToken': response1.idToken,
         'expirationTime': user.lastLoginAt + Number(response1.expiresIn)
       },
       'redirectEventId': null,
       'lastLoginAt': user.lastLoginAt,
       'createdAt': user.createdAt
    };
```

Then in cybress, I simply save this object in local storag, in the before hook: `localStorage.setItem(`firebase:authUser:${apiKey}:[DEFAULT]`, authObject);`

Maybe not perfect, but it solves the problem. Let me know if you interested in the code, and if you have any knowledge about how to build the "authObject", or solve this problem in another way.

Comment: Unfortunately Firebase just switched over to indexedDB, so this localstorage solution no longer works.