# How to use Firebase Auth's Google Sign-In option with Cypress.io

Tags: node.js, firebase, integration-testing, google-authentication, cypress

I need help using Google Sign-In when testing my Angular 6 app with Cypress. It can't use the sign-in popup, and so I'm trying to follow Cypress' advice to "always use `cy.request()` to talk to 3rd party servers via their APIs." That's from https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Visiting-external-sites which then points us to this example: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/logging-in__single-sign-on/cypress/integration/logging-in-single-sign-on-spec.js - more info on how to do this is seen at minute 23 in a presentation by the Cypress author: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XQOK0v_YRE

I'm taking the video solution and trying to modify it for Firebase Auth according to https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#advanced-authenticate-with-firebase-in-nodejs but I'm getting stuck on how to obtain the proper `id_token` and so far I have this code in my commands.js file:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
  var id_token = ___?____;
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key=[API_KEY]',
    body: {
      "requestUri": "http://localhost:3500",
      "postBody": `id_token=${id_token}&providerId=google.com`,
      "returnSecureToken": true,
      "returnIdpCredential": true
    }
  })
})
```

I believe I need to use a different API to initiate the login and request user credentials, which will include the id_token, and so I tried https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#advanced-authenticate-with-firebase-in-nodejs but am not yet skilled enough to pull in external js files (https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js) into Node (This is probably not possible in js files the way it is in html). Using this package: https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs may be my next attempt. Is there anyone who can pick it up from here?

Similar question at [Is it possible to use Cypress e2e testing with a firebase auth project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735570/is-it-possible-to-use-cypress-e2e-testing-with-a-firebase-auth-project) - but they are signing in  with user and pass.

Comment: any solution on this?

Comment: No solution with Google Auth yet, though you can work around it by just using email+pass authentication as that is testable.

Comment: is there a link that would walk me though setting that up or did you just trial and error though it?

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to setting up Cypress, and not email+pass auth. I don't have any link or example because I never carried it out, I'm not doing much on testing at the moment, though I hope to do more in the future. I have pretty limited hours and am just working on a small project so I'm not doing end-to-end at the moment.
If you need help on setting up email+pass auth, I'd be glad to share a repo link.

Comment: yeah a link to email+pass repo would be a great!  Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Maybe start with https://fireship.io/lessons/angularfire-google-oauth/ as that's where I got my start. Then check out my user module at https://github.com/jacobbowdoin/talking-dictionaries/tree/develop/src/app/user (the login-form component and signup-form component) and my auth service at https://github.com/jacobbowdoin/talking-dictionaries/blob/develop/src/app/core/auth.service.ts to see how I've added email+pass auth to the Google auth he demoed.